# SQL query to find same ID but different names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
ID  | name
45    Alex 
98    Diana
32    Peter
98    Daniel
45    Alex
23    Bob
98    Jake
```

I need to find all rows where is the same ID but different name.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (select 1
              from mytable t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.name <> t.name
             );
```

Comment: Not sure what to use instead variables.

`select my-table.*
from my-table
where exists (select 1 from my-table t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.name <> t.name);`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `first/last value()` window functions here:

```
with n as (
    select *, 
    First_Value(name) over(partition by id order by (select null)) n1, 
    Last_Value(name) over(partition by id order by (select null)) n2
    from t
)
select Id, Name
from n
where n1 != n2
```

Answer (score 1):

A windowed count is usually the most efficient:

```sql
SELECT
  t.ID, 
  t.name
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      c = COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY t.name)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE c > 1;
```

Comment: This gives me list of same names on same IDs. I need same names on different IDs.

Comment: So just change the `PARTITION BY` clause, have edited. Your question says "where is the same ID but different name"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
ID,
name,
CASE WHEN COUNT(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) = 1 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NOT OK' END AS CountID
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID,name
ORDER BY ID
```

Example:

[image: Example]